# Youtube video upload in C# .NET fails after first chunk is sent

Tags: c#, .net, upload, youtube

I have a c# application which upload videos to youtube. Here is the code i've used

```
 UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "ABCD",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] {"Tag1", "Tag2"};
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = 22; 
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "private"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = @"C:\myvideo.mp4"; 

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += uploadProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += uploadCompleted;

                const int KB = 0x400;
                var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;
                videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 4;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }
```

But the code failes after first chunk is sent. The `uploadProgressChanged` method receives a status that the first chunk is uploaded (1 MB, as specified). Soon after that it receives another status that the upload failed. Why does this happen? I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
    Video newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title ="My Test Movie";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
newVideo.Description = "My description";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", 
  YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
// alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
// newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Mountain View, CA");

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("c:\\file.mov",
  "video/quicktime");
Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet?csw=1#Direct_Upload